# Can I use FirstOrDefault() or First() inside Where()

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am trying to implement this query:

```
 data.Where(d => d.ObjectsA != null && 
   d.ObjectsA.First().ObjectsB != null && 
   d.ObjectsA.First().ObjectsB().First().Nr == 1)
```

in Nhibernate.Linq, but I have an error.
When I delete First() from Where() all work.
I try this solution but this don't get what I need.

```
 data.Where(d => d.ObjectsA.Where(a.ObjectsB.Where(b=>b.Nr == 1).Any()).Any());
```

Can I use FirstOrDefault() or First() inside Where() ?

EDIT : In my DB tables all rows in this example don't have null values.

Answer (score 3):

[First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) will throw an exception if the collection is empty. Using [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) in your `Where()` call should indeed solve the problem, but you would have to write something like:

```
data.Where(d => d.ObjectsA != null && d.ObjectsA.Any()
    && d.ObjectsA.First().ObjectsB != null && d.ObjectsA.First().ObjectsB.Any()
    && d.ObjectsA.First().ObjectsB.First().Nr == 1);
```

That's not very nice, because `First()` ends up being called several times on the same data. I'd suggest adding a body to your lambda expression and using intermediate variables with [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx):

```
data.Where(d => {
    if (d.ObjectsA != null) {
        var firstA = d.ObjectsA.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstA != null && firstA.ObjectsB != null) {
            var firstB = firstA.ObjectsB.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstB != null) {
                return (firstB.Nr == 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT:** The second code fragment above apparently does not work with LINQ to NHibernate. If you can use query syntax and don't have to check if `ObjectsA` and `ObjectsB` are `null`, you can write:

```
from d in data
let firstA = d.ObjectsA.FirstOrDefault()
let firstB = (firstA != null ? firstA.ObjectsB.FirstOrDefault() : null)
where (firstB != null && firstB.Nr == 1)
select d;
```

Comment: Error: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: @Artiom, ouch, I forgot that detail. So it seems you have no other choice than to use the first code sample with LINQ to NHibernate, even if calling `First()` repeatedly like that doesn't look right...

Comment: Yes,unfortunately. But why Where() throw exception when I use First or FirstOrDefault() inside ? I don't have empty collections.

Comment: @Artiom, that's hard to answer without knowing the exact exception that's thrown. Can you add that information to your question?

Comment: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. [.Where[Project.Core.Model.Document](.OrderByDescending[Project.Core.Model.Document,System.DateTime](.Where[Project.Core.Model.Document](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Project.Core.Model.Document], Quote((d, ) => (NotEqual(d.Contractant, NULL))), ), Quote((d, ) => (d.DataRealizare)), ), Quote((d, ) => (.Any[Project.Core.Model.Rata](.Where[Project.Core.Model.Rata](d.Rate, (r, ) => (AndAlso(Equal(r.NrRata, p1), GreaterThan(.FirstOrDefault[Project.Core.Model.Plata](r.Plati, ).Id, p2))), ), ))), )]

Comment: @Artiom, I see, it's the dreaded `NoViableAltException`. I can make much out of it, but maybe you can use the tool described [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770672/nhibernate-how-to-debug-antlr-runtime-noviablealtexception) to get a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If the collections used in the condition can be empty, you can use a default variable and the ?? nullif operator with FirstOrDefault().

```
var defaultA = new ObjectA();
var defaultB = new ObjectB();
var defaultBList = new List<ObjectB>();

data.Where(d => d.ObjectsA != null && 
   ((d.ObjectsA.FirstOrDefault() ?? defaultA).ObjectsB ?? defaultBList)
   .FirstOrDefault() ?? defaultB).Nr == 1)
```